# How can I access cookies in a jQuery("iframe").contents() object?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, iframe

I'm trying to use jquery to get hold of cookies that have been sent in a response in an iframe.
I can actually see the cookies in the chrome dev tools console but I can't get hold of them programmatically.

When i run this code:
`if (jQuery("iframe#someId")){
    var conts = jQuery("iframe#someId").contents()
    console.log(conts)
}`, I see this in the console
[image]

If I try to access the context "child" with `jQuery("iframe#someId").contents().find("context")` I only get the DOM elements, the cookies are not availble.
The code `console.log(conts.find('context').get('cookie'))` just prints `undefined`

Does anyone have any clue on how to read the cookie value from the `conts` object in the first code snippet?

By the way, I do not have any control over the server, the script I'm trying to write is injected into the page in the browser via a chrome extension (Custom JavaScript for websites). So there's no way I can change anything on the server side

Comment: Is the IFrame domain the same domain that you are serving your JavaScript from?

Comment: @pwdst, the script is loaded from a data:text/javascript uri. The chrome extension saves it in the local storage if I understand it correct. But assuming that the object that is printed to the console actually is the iframe's content, the script already have some access to the data. I just haven't found a way to get only the cookie data out of the jquery object

Comment: I tried to get out of jQuery land with this `var context = jQuery("iframe#someId").contents().get('context');` so I get a "raw" javascript object. Then I could actually read the cookies with `if (context.cookie) {console.log(console.cookie);}`